# Valid Name Checker REGEX

Tags: java, regex, string

I am writing a code that takes a person's name and sees if it fits the REGEX criteria. If it does, it follows through a loop and continues on with the code. If the name is not valid, the code will exit. So far I have made it so it can take input and check the names. It is working for all except 2 names. O’Malley, John F. and John O’Malley-Smith. These two names need to be acceptable but the code keeps kicking them out saying they are invalid.

So far I have attempted using

```
String REGEX = ("^[\\-\\.\\'\\, a-zA-Z ]*$");
```

This gets me a solid return on all the names except for the 2 mentioned above. I know I have to add somethings to the REGEX code, and have attempted \b boundaries, however have had no luck getting them to work. Any help would be appreciated on what I should add to the REGEX and where to put it inside the code. Here is also the list of valid and invalid names, as well as my code.

Acceptable inputs for name:
Bruce Schneier

Schneier, Bruce

Schneier, Bruce Wayne

O’Malley, John F.

John O’Malley-Smith

Cher

Unacceptable inputs for name:
Ron O’’Henry

Ron O’Henry-Smith-Barnes

L33t Hacker

//alert(“XSS”)//

select * from users;

(All Invalid Names Are Not Accepted At This Time)

```
public class InputAsker {
    public static void main (String[]args) {

        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Please Input Your Name: ");
        
        String myName = keyboard.nextLine();
        
        
        
        String REGEX = ("^[\\-\\.\\'\\, a-zA-Z ]*$");
        

        
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
        
        
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myName);
        
        
        boolean matchfound = false;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("That's A Great Name! Let's Continue");
  
            matchfound = true;
            
            //loop will continue here
        }
        
       
        
        
        if (!matchfound) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, Not A Valid Name! Please Try Again!");
            
        }
        
        
       
        
        
        
        
        
    }

        
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Why would `Ron O’Henry-Smith-Barnes` not be valid?

Comment: IDK it's not my criteria, I wasn't the one who came up with the invalid names.

Comment: But it is your question, there must be a rule that should make that string not a valid match. Is it like using 2 hyphens? Do you have more example strings?

Comment: Oh I actually forgot I posted this haha. I figured it out, thanks for trying though.